# Angular Inject Pipe in Service

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

I have created below service for formatting data. The service is called from angular component and `guest.vo.ts` returns back the processed data

### guest.vo.ts

```
import { Guest } from '../core/guest/guest.model';
import { TimeAgoPipe } from 'angular2-moment/time-ago.pipe';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export default class GuestVO {
  constructor(private timeAgo: TimeAgoPipe) {}
  getVO(guests: Guest[]) {
    return guests.map(guest => {
      let vo: any = {};
      vo.created = this.timeAgo.transform(guest.created);
      return vo;
    });
  }
}
```

I am using the below library for time calculation
https://github.com/urish/angular2-moment/blob/master/src/time-ago.pipe.ts

However, I am facing errors while injecting TimeAgoPipe in Service as it depends on ChangeDetectorRef.
This problem doesn't occur if I use TimeAgoPipe directly in Component.
Any recommendations on using this Pipe?

```
constructor(
    private cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef, 
    private ngZone: NgZone) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*Pipe*-s are not injectable. You can just add it into the `declarations` of the module and just use it. If you want to inject a pipe, you can provide it as a service like

```
{ provide: MyPipe, useClass: TimeAgoPipe }
```

and inject it's instance as `MyPipe`

Comment: gotcha. if i add in declarations, how do i access in service?

Comment: The purpose of the pipe to access it in the template. If you want to access it in the component, you need to create an instance of it in it, but it will be better to use provider for it. But the best to use it in the template